# find what program is using port on remote computer

Tags: java

How to do it using JAVA? I can find what port is used or not used by iteration through all ports

```
tcp = new Socket(remote_address, i); // i [0 - 65535]
tcp.setReuseAddress(true);
```

But how to find what application is using this port?

Comment: I believe there's nmap wrapper for Java. Maybe you should google that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really hard to find this using java . You have to write a quite large codes checking various characteristics of ports for this . If u google about this , you can get more details regarding this . Actually some requests has to be send to the port . Now various applications running behind that port will respond with particular headers/banners/format which you will be using to check against various pre set conditions . But this is not a 100% accurate way .

Smart Net Admins can fake you by putting up decoys behind the port .

Instead ,you can use Nmap for this . Its a command line tool used in linux/windows/mac that can help you find quite a lot information about port.

Comment: I don't want to use library. The task is to write on my own. Maybe I should use another language? С++ & WinAPI?

Comment: @user1432980 No, changing languages isn't going to help. It's the initial premise of the problem that makes it difficult.

Comment: Actually what various tools does is that , it send a particular reuest and sees the response it receives . Now it checks against various preset conditions and predict the type of application running on that port . And its not 100% accurate results as various decoys wmay be set up by net admins to fake scanning

Comment: @ShuhailKadavath mail server on a random port, and some BS on 25 xD

Comment: Oh! So I need just to send request to address and port and the parse the result?

Comment: @user1432980 that's pretty much it. You just make some guesses, the response will be different on every application.

Comment: Yes .. But also if a firewall is present , it can help you to just capture your request and not send a response at all

Comment: Of course another way to mitigate attacks would be to have the server reject connections from someone sending it bogus requests... (Although that's mostly hypothetical on my part.)

Answer (score 2):

You can't really determine this. Any application can send any stream of data over TCP, and for security reasons, this information is not exposed remotely. You can, however, probe the port with different messages and see what happens, allowing you to experimentally infer the application.

In addition, some services/protocols will have distinctive greetings, headers, and messages, and can even expose debugging information.

Comment: OP can see this for themselves by telnetting the port and see what the responses look like.